# Real function injectivity proof

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

How can one prove that the real function $f(x) = (1-x)x^{\frac{x}{1-x}}$ is an injection?

Comment: Use contratiction: $f(a_1) = f(a_2) \Rightarrow a_1 = a_2$

Comment: What is the domain of the map? Have you tried computing derivatives? If the domain is an interval, it should have positive derivative everywhere or negative derivative everywhere on that interval.

Comment: Without you giving/finding the domain of definition of this function the question makes no sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $f(x)= (1-x)x^{\frac{x}{1-x}}$, taking logarithm on both sides you will get $logf(x)=log(1-x)+{\frac{x}{1-x}}logx$. Then differentiating with respect to x, we will have ${\frac{1}{f(x)}}f'(x)={\frac{1}{1-x}}(-1)+{\frac{x}{1-x}}{\frac{1}{x}}+(logx)({\frac{1}{1-x}})^2$. I think this will help

Comment: yup, the domain is (0,1) - i think the derivative is negative. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Directly: for $\,0<x<1\;$

$$f(x)=(1-x)e^{\frac x{1-x}\log x}\implies $$

$$f'(x)=-e^{\frac x{1-x}\log x}+(1-x)e^{\frac x{1-x}\log x}\left(\frac{\log x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac1{1-x}\right)=$$

$$=e^{\frac x{1-x}\log x}\left(\frac{\log x}{1-x}\right)<0$$